# x_sendfile does not load

Tags: php, apache, module, x-sendfile

I'm trying to install x_sendfile in apache web server on a Mac OS X Server.
Everything seems fine with the installation and the httpd.conf is configured with
**"LoadModule xsendfile_module libexec/apache2/mod_xsendfile.so"**
and
**"XSendFile ON"**.

If I run **"httpd -M"** from the terminal I can se **"xsendfile_module (shared)"** in the list.

But in phpinfo() or apache_get_modules() x-sendfile is not listed. If i try to use x-sendfile in my php code to download any file, the browser just downloads a 0 kb file.
I can see the x-sendfile header tag in the header data though.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have this line in your `httpd.conf` file. Add it under settings for your page:

```
<Directory "/var/www/html">
    XSendFile On
    XSendFilePath /dir-where-the-file-gets-downloaded-from/
<Directory>
```

Comment: This I have done already. Is there no way to try to force load a module from the terminal to see what happens?
I get no errors in the log.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered a similar issue with CentOS. I added:

```
XSendFile On 
XSendFilePath /dir-where-the-file-gets-downloaded-from/
```

to the `httpd.conf`, however I also made sure to use absolute paths on the PHP page itself

```
header('Content-Type: '.$formatMIME);
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary"); 
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=User_sees_this.pdf"); 
header("X-Sendfile: 'absolute_path_goes_here'");
```

As far as I can tell if `httpd -M` is showing the module as installed, the code above should work. You will not see `xsendfile` in `phpinfo` because it is not an extension of PHP. I can't speak to `apache_get_modules()`.

Again, this is a comment based on my personal experience and not intended to be a definitive answer.